# How do you remove the UITableView Edit cell drop shadow?

Tags: ios, uitableview, styling

I have an image of what is happening:

[image]

How do I get rid of that drop-shadow?

Comment: Any updates on this? I would like to know the same answer.

Comment: none. as you can see no one responded and I've been working on other projects :-/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Try this in cellForRowAtIndexPath, Its works like Charm !!!!**

```
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0f;
```

Comment: It has no effect on a shadow dropped from the cell when in isEditing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 solution; use extended uitableviewcontroller because now shadow is in the table and only added when cell is moved.

```
class UITableViewControllerEx: UITableViewController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        view.subviews.filter({ String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UIShadowView" }).forEach { (sv: UIView) in
            sv.alpha = 0
        }
    }

}
```